# ManyToMany field, check if relation exists

Tags: django

```
class Player(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    box = models.ManyToManyField(Test)
```

views:

```
a = Player.object.get(id=1)
b = Player.objects.get(id=5)
```

How to check if `a.item` is in ManyToMany relation with `b.box`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
Playes.objects.filter(pk=a.pk, box__pk=b.pk).exists()
```